# How can I check when a DbMigration is applied to a database?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I'm using Entity Framework Code First Migrations. I want to track DbMigrations applied to a database.

For example, for a specific DbMigration, say `201501023659_Init` I want to know:

- **when** does it applied to database
- **who** updated the database
- What was the version of software at the update time (not the version of EF)

In the `dbo.__MigrationHistory` table, there is not enough information about how the DbMigration is applied. Even for time of applying, there is no column.

**Question 1:** For a specific DbMigration, is there way to find out when and how does it applied?

**Question 2:** If the answer of Question 1 is no, then How can I customize the columns of `dbo.__MigrationHistory` and fill them at the time of database update.

Comment: It sounds like you have automatic migrations on and want to audit who caused the DB to be updated. Is that correct?

Comment: @Vlad274 No, the automatic migration is off. The Release Management updates database. But I want to have a history on migrations. When a specific migration is applied. The When part is more important than Who part!